# Generating large sets of random data vb6/vb net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Is there an easy way in either language to generate a large set of random data quickly so far all the functions I've tried haven't worked too well when I need to generate a group of say 500,000 characters :(  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> Use UUIDGen.

Don't. GUIDs aren't really random. You can actually generate large amounts of data very fast using the `System.Random` class in VB.NET. 500,000 characters/bytes are no problem:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() = Nothing
Array.Resize(buffer, 500000)
Call New Random().NextBytes(buffer)
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("filename", buffer, False)
```

This code takes *considerably* less than one second.

Comment: And software random generators aren't truly random, you need a good hardware random generator for that. But for many applications the pseudo random number from the software random generator is random enough.

Comment: I think in a programming context we can assume that PRNGs are sufficient, if not otherwise stated. If not, well, yes, then things can get a lot slower (although I've got no experience with the speed of Windows’ entropy generator / hardware random device, which should be close enough to true random).

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 the code would go something like this

```
Public Function FillRandomCol() as Collection
    Dim C As Collection
    Dim I As Long
    Set C = New Collection
    Randomize Timer
    For I = 1 To 500000
        C.Add RandomChar
    Next I
    Set FillRandomCol = C
End Sub

Public Function Random(ByVal Number As Integer) As Integer
    Random = CLng(Rnd * 1000000) Mod Number + 1
End Function

Public Function RandomChar() As String
    Const AlphaNum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    RandomChar = Mid$(AlphaNum, Random(36), 1)
End Function
```

Takes 1/2 second on a 2 Core Intel 2.40 GHz computer.

Answer (score -1):

Use [UUIDGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526809(EXCHG.10).aspx). At least the chunks will be bigger.